# Calculate datetime difference in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

Hi I was solving a problem to calculate some library fine based on difference in return date and due date in C#. Now there are some constraints to the problem like

> if the return year is changed i.e. **if the return year is greater than the due date calendar year** then fine is 10000. e.g. due date "31/12/2015" and return date "01/01/2016" then also fine is 10000.
>
> if the return month is changed then fine is 500 * number of months late.
>
> if the return day is changed then fine is 15 * number of days late.
>
> else fine is 0.

Now i wrote the function below:

```
static int CalcFine (int[] returnedOn, int[] dueOn) {
    int returnD = returnedOn[0];
    int returnM = returnedOn[1];
    int returnY = returnedOn[2];
    int dueD = dueOn[0];
    int dueM = dueOn[1];
    int dueY = dueOn[2];

    if (returnY > dueY) {
        return 10000;
    } else if (returnY < dueY) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (returnM > dueM) {
            return (returnM - dueM) * 500;
        } else if (returnM < dueM) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (returnD > dueD) {
                return (returnD - dueD) * 15;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I read about the DateTime class in C# that has pretty neat functions that return the difference in two dates as total days, total minutes, etc. But given the constraint of **Fine** being different based on year, month and days, I am not sure if there is any other inbuilt function to solve the above problem. In short I am trying to find if there is another simple way to solve the above problem without using so many if-else's.

Comment: This looks like the hackerrank question from 30-days of code. The `DateTime` class is more that sufficient to tackle this problem. How do I know this? Because I used it to solve this.

Comment: What if day, month and year are all changed? It's possible.

Comment: Are the parameters also constrained to be two int arrays?

Comment: If year is changed then fine is 10000, no matter whether the day and month changed or not. So basically the priority is like if year changed then 10000, if only month changed then 500 * months changed, and if only days changed then 15 * days changed.

Comment: Paolo, the input is basically a space separated string which i converted to int arrays. I am still getting myself familiar with C# inbuilt classes so went a little long way. I believe there is much better way to convert space separated string to date. e.g. "31 12 2015" to datetime object "31/12/2015"

Comment: Subtraction of `DateTime` returns a `TimeSpan` object which represents the time interval but it is not useful in your case. In fact your code is clear and simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference in days, hours or minutes.

```
DateTime fromdate = new DateTime(2012,1,1);
DateTime todate = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan diff = todate - fromdate;
int differenceInDays = diff.Days;
```

If you want to try differently for your validations and business rules. Follow the below code

```
public double GetFineAmount(DateTime DueDate)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    int yeardiff, monthdiff, daydiff;

    yeardiff = dt.Year - DueDate.Year;
    if (yeardiff > 0) return 10000;
    monthdiff = dt.Month - DueDate.Month;
    if (monthdiff > 0) return 500 * monthdiff;
    daydiff = dt.Day - DueDate.Day;
    if (daydiff > 0) return 15 * daydiff;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Getting difference in days is very easy using the DateTime class. But my question is to solve weird usecases where due date is "31/12/2015" and return date is "01/01/2016". Although in days its just In this case the output should be 10000 since the book is returned after the current calendar year. The diff.Days would just return 1 days.

Comment: @Naphstor Well, you'll obviously need to use more than just the difference between the dates.  But `DateTime` will handle the dates for you cleanly. In the case for years, you'd simply write: `if (DateTime.Now.Year - checkoutDate.Year) >= 1)`, etc.

Comment: Then you have to do something like. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Editted again.. changed string pattern. I guess I need some sleep...

```
    static int CalcFine (string returnedOn, string dueOn)
    {
        DateTime returnedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            returnedOn, "d M yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime dueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
            dueOn, "d M yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (returnedDate < dueDate)
            return 0;
        if (returnedDate.Year > dueDate.Year)
            return 10000;
        if (returnedDate.Month > dueDate.Month)
            return 500 * (returnedDate.Month - dueDate.Month);
        if (returnedDate.Day > dueDate.Day)
            return 15 * (returnedDate.Day - dueDate.Day);
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is different from Naphstor's one. For example, if return date is 2015-12-31 and due due date is 2016-1-1, Naphstor' code returns 0 but your code returns 5500.

Comment: Paolo, if the return date is "2/7/2015" and due date is "1/1/2016" then the output should be 0. Mongo, my code returns 10000 in the usecase you mentioned. As I am checking for the year different in very first if condition.

Comment: @Naphstor Have you tried this solution? I think this satisfies the conditions you stated

Comment: @Naphstor I editted my solution, it should accept two space separate date string of the format `date` `month` `year`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a powerful tool. But you don't want to over-complicate this.

If you just find the difference between the two dates in days, the equation becomes a lot easier to manage versus trying to subtract dates.

```
static int CalcFine(DateTime returnedOn, DateTime dueOn)
    {

        TimeSpan dateDiff = (returnedOn - dueOn);
        int TotalDays = dateDiff.Days;
        if (TotalDays >= 365)
        {
            return 10000;
        }
        else if(TotalDays < 365 && TotalDays > 30 && TotalDays % 30 > 1)
        {
            return (500 * (TotalDays % 30));
        }
        else if(TotalDays < 30 && TotalDays > 0)
        {
            return 15 * TotalDays;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought of this solution but it will fail in the condition where due date is "31/12/2015" and return date is "01/01/2016". In this case the output should be 10000 since the book is returned after the current calendar year. Although unreal but its part of problem.

Comment: That's not right, the code provided returns 15. It runs from top to bottom, and it's not checking if the year changed. It's simply checking the number of days. In this case, timespan returns 1.

Comment: @Kramb Yes, and what he's saying is that this solution is incorrect. The requirement is that if the year changes, it's a fine of 10,000, not if a year has passed. The result should be 10000, not 15.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you @Rob. I thought this was a real world scenario.